# How to retrieve Contact from InfusionSoft XML-RPC API?

Tags: xml-rpc, infusionsoft

I am attempting to access the contact information from InfusionSoft.  I have had a lot of success with their REST API but I need to use the XML-RPC API for some fields.

I am using the package "infusionsoft-client"
https://github.com/theY4Kman/infusionsoft-client

The example that they provided works to add a contact.  However, when I try to retrieve the contact information I cannot seem to format it correctly.

Here is what I have tried.

```
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'contactId': 1, 'selectedFields': ('FirstName', 'LastName')})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': 'FirstName', 'LastName'})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': ['FirstName', 'LastName']})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': "['FirstName', 'LastName']"})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'privateKey': <my_key>, 'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': ['FirstName', 'LastName']})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'privateKey': <my_key>, 'contactId': 1, 'selectedFields': ('FirstName', 'LastName')})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'privateKey': <my_key>, 'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': 'FirstName', 'LastName'})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load({'privateKey': <my_key>, 'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': ['FirstName', 'LastName']})
infusionsoft.ContactService.load(<my_key>, {'contactId': 11, 'selectedFields': ['FirstName', 'LastName']})
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have tried formatting it exactly like the docs SAY and also tried the example given in the docs.
https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-retrieve-a-contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working.

```
infusionsoft.initialize(INFUSIONSOFT_APP_NAME, INFUSIONSOFT_API_KEY)
    args = {"contactId" : "9", "selectedFields":['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Password']}
    contactId = args['contactId']
    selectedFields = args['selectedFields']
    my_contact = infusionsoft.ContactService.load(contactId, selectedFields)
```

Comment: Did you try infusionsoft.OrderService('placeOrder', order) ?? if you did how you are passing arguments ?? please give an example as well

Comment: I have not used the OrderService at all yet.